# Yarn keeps on killing Spark Application master on EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I'm running a spark application on  EMR emr-4.3.0 with 1 Master and 4 Nodes

Each one of them has 5GB memory and 2 cores.

The following are my spark-submit options

> --class com.mobi.vserv.driver.Query5kPids1
>   --num-executors 4
>   --executor-memory 4g
>   --executor-cores 2
>   --driver-memory 4g

But I keep getting the following error

> ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Driver
>   10.225.19.144:56334 disassociated! Shutting down.

And finally Yarn Kills the Application master

> ERROR ApplicationMaster: RECEIVED SIGNAL 15: SIGTERM

1) Can I further Improve my spark-submit options for num-executors and executor-cores.

2) I have seen in the Perfomance Graph only 2 nodes CPU's utilization is above 50 % , while the other 2 has less than 5 %.

3) Interestingly , I have ran the same application on 2 nodes and 1 master with the same configurations given in Spark-submit and the application ran successfully. So whats the reason of this behaviour with 4 nodes

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: any solutions? @halil

Comment: @neverwinter Not that I remember now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

When running spark with yarn, it's never a good thing to manually force number of executor instance, use `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true` instead.

This way spark will ask yarn politely, if it can have more resources to run, if yarn has, it will grant it.

To find the root cause of your scenario you need to see how much memory yarn has on yarn's application ui (default port 8088 on namenode).
Since you are specifying yourself the memory for each executor, yarn can only allocate instance of that size, and also, yarn has to reserve a set of vCores and Memory reserve for next task.

You can use "yarn -applicationId app_name_id", to find application log on yarn, if it has an issue.

Comment: Hi Abhishek thanks for the answer , So you are saying only give only  spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true for spark-submit, what about executor memory and driver memory ? Please answer.

Comment: You should definitely specify number of cores for executor, driver, master and memory for them. But for executor, you will have to find out, what core/memory combination works best for your cluster. In general 1 gb memory to 1 core work good. Try not to make executor set big or very small.  You can go through http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

Comment: Also you said , 1 GB memory for 1 core , i guess you meant 1 Executor ?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I ran the application with the following options --class com.mobi.vserv.driver.Query5kPids1
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
--executor-memory 2g
--executor-cores 2
--driver-memory 4g           But the same result also yarn killed the application master and in the log I also found this                                         INFO YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers
16/03/29 14:24:49                                                                              WARN YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.